# I can't find a specific mob's health

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to check a PVP bot's health, except every time I try to. it says it can't. Here is my current command:

```
/execute if entity @e[name=Skeleton] [nbt={Health:10.0f}] run setblock 49 157 81 redstone_block
```

Here is the error message:

> Incorrect argument or command ...Skeleton] (red text starts here) [nbt={Health:10.0f}] run setblock 49 157 81 redstone_block*<--[HERE]* .

I've tried playing around with the command, asking friends, and now I'm here, so please help.
Version: 1.19.2.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

> /execute if entity @e[name=Skeleton,nbt={Health:10.0f}] run setblock 49 157 81 redstone_block

It worked in my test world. Your problem was that you needed a comma between `[name=Skeleton` and `nbt={Health:10.0f}]` instead of a space and brackets